# How to get the youtube videos by user

Tags: android, video, youtube

I want to display a certain youtube channel's videos in list view, and allow the user to select one of their videos to watch. Is there Any Json Data is Available for this.?

**EDIT**

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos? 
                  author=NationalGeographic&v=2&alt=json");    

try{
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("feed");    
     for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
            map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

i have permissions and the url working in tab , i am getting nullpointer error @JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("feed");

Comment: First off, you are using the wrong URL. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would hit the URL below, replacing USERNAME with the user in question:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

You can test out the calls [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses.html).

**Edit**

If you are looking for NationalGeographic, the URL to hit would be:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NationalGeographic/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

You would find the video url like this:

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NationalGeographic/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");    
final JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data"); 
final JSONArray array = data.getJSONArray("items");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    final JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
    final JSONObject player = item.getJSONObject("player");
    final String url = player.getString("default"));
    // The url is that of the video to be played
}
```

Try/catch code omitted for brevity.

Comment: what is the json Object to get videos

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Version 3.0 API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Youtube APIs to get this data

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience.html

Refer to the Searching Channels section

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search.html

Comment: You will get the response in a xml format from which you can extract the list of entries

Comment: See edited my question..i have permissions and the url working in tab , i am getting nullpointer error @JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("feed");

Comment: @RajdeepDua - why send him to a long-winded article when you can simply give the exact URL to hit. Also, he is clearly asking for a JSON response.